# Serilog Elasticsearch

Tags: asp.net-core, elasticsearch, microservices

i have a microservice api where I try to log all the request which come in...so the elasticsaerch service and kibana are on a different server. I'm using the serilog.sinks.elasticsearch package to send data to the elasticsearch.

Both servers are not running with docker, they are just normal windows server.

My code looks like this to setup the logging...

```
        public static Logger Create(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            var elasticsearchSection = configuration.GetSection("Elasticsearch");
            if (elasticsearchSection != null)
            {
                return CreateLoggerConfiguration(elasticsearchSection).CreateLogger();
            }
            return null;
        }

        private static LoggerConfiguration CreateLoggerConfiguration(IConfigurationSection section)
        {
            var loggerConfiguration = new LoggerConfiguration();

            var url = section.GetValue<string>("Url");
            var minimumLogLevel = section.GetValue<string>("MinimumLogLevel");
            var minimumLogEventLevel = section.GetValue<string>("MinimumLogEventLevel");

            SetLoggerConfigurationMinimumLogLevel(minimumLogLevel, loggerConfiguration);

            loggerConfiguration.WriteTo.Elasticsearch(new ElasticsearchSinkOptions(GetLoggingUri(url))
            {
                MinimumLogEventLevel = ReturnLogEventLevel(minimumLogEventLevel),
                AutoRegisterTemplate = true
            });
            loggerConfiguration.Enrich.FromLogContext();

            return loggerConfiguration;
        }
```

And in my startup,cs I'm using
`services.AddLogging(loggingBuilder => loggingBuilder.AddSerilog(dispose: true));`

in the ConfigureServices Method...

But apparently I cant create an Index inside my Kibana.

Any ideas why this isnt working?

Comment: Is there any error message when debug your application? And, can you tell us when/where you will call the Create method to configure the Serilog (it is better to post the related code in the Startup.cs and the Program.cs file)? From the following links, it seems that we could configure the Serilog in the Program.Mian method, please check them: [Logging With ElasticSearch, Kibana, Serilog Using ASP.NET Core Docker](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/logging-with-elasticsearch-kibana-serilog-using-asp-net-core-docker/) and [Serilog.AspNetCore](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-aspnetcore).

Comment: Thanks for your reply :) . As I said we have 2 seperate Servers one where our Microservice is running on an IIS Server and the other Server where we mainly have our Kibana & Elasticsearch running. I have it all in the Startup.cs method and the complete configuration in an other class so Startup.cs doesn't look bloated.  Both of these servers dont use docker. And on my local machine I had docker configured and there it worked. Maybe I'm missing a parameter but I dont know which one.

Comment: And as far as I understand Serilog.Sinks.Elasticsearch correctly it should stream the data from my application to my elasticsearch without any other configuration like logging it into an file and transfer it with filebeat or something like that...